# Many to one and primary key says property not found on entity

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

I have a parent and child entity like the below.

**Parent**

```
@Entity(name="Test1")
public class Test1 implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="PK1")
    public int pk1;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PK2")
    public int pk2;

    @Column(name="fld")
    public int fld;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pt3l", referencedColumnName = "P1")
    public Test3 fldl;
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity(name="Test2")
public class Test2 implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="PK21")
    public int pk21;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="s1", referencedColumnName = "PK1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="s2", referencedColumnName = "PK2")
    })
    public Test1 fld21;

    @Column(name="FLD21")
    public int fld22;

}
```

When I make the `@ManyToOne` field in the child id then I got below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: property [pk21] not found on entity [he.db.Test2]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getProperty(PersistentClass.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getProperty(PersistentClass.java:470)
```

In my scenario I have made the parent table field as well primary key in the child.

Comment: please format your question properly. It increases the chances that someone might look into it. I did it with this question as an example

Comment: Do you really have two Id annotation in each class? I don't think this is supposed to work.

Comment: Two id is working. But in the second class only i got the problem. Interesting thing is it is creating child table with s1,s2 fields as primary keys also the PK21 as well.

Comment: @Rooban your mapping is bizarre: do you want to achieve a one to one relationship? Test1 reference Test2 and Test2 reference Test1?